# Typescript: pass Parameters<T> tuple of generic function type parameter as variadic arguments

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript4.0

In Typescript 4.1.x you can [spread tuple types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types) into functions as variadic arguments.

```js
type MyTuple = [string, number];
const myTuple: MyTuple = ["blob", 42];

function tupleFunc(s: string, n: number): void {
    console.log(`${s} ${n}`);
}

tupleFunc(...myTuple); // ✅ A-Ok
```

However, I'm hitting an error when the tuple is derived from a generic type parameter and using the [`Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype).

```js
function foo(a: number, b: boolean, c: string) {
  return 10;
}

foo(1, true, "baz") // 10 ✅

function bar(...params: Parameters<typeof foo>) {
    return foo(...params)
}

bar(1, true, "baz") // 10 ✅

function bar2<F extends typeof foo>(...params: Parameters<F>) {
  //  next line would work
  //  return foo(params[0], params[1], params[2])

  return foo(...params); // Fails 
  // Expected 3 arguments, but got 0 or more.ts(2556)
  // index.ts(28, 14): An argument for 'a' was not provided.
}
```

Is there a way to make this concept pass the type checker or is it not supported in typescript? Although it errors, it seems to work in the Typescript sandbox. [See an example here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Seems like I can get it to work with `.apply()`, but I'd love to know if there's another way.

```
function bar3<T extends typeof foo>(...params: Parameters<T>) {
  return foo.apply(null, params);
}
```

Comment: What’s the use case here?  Can you show how you intend to call `bar2`?  I’m trying to figure out which workarounds would work for you but I think I’m not seeing the point of `F`.  What narrower types that extend `typeof foo` are you trying to support?

Comment: This is a simplified example, but you could imagine scenarios where `F` is less bounded. In such cases, I could create a wrapper around any function shape `F` that matches its shape and does some checks before conditionally passing along its arguments to an implementation `f: F`

Comment: I think if you are operating over different possible parameter lists and return types, you might want to use those as your generic type parameters instead of the function type... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMZrW).  But this depends on your use cases I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is interesting and I don't know if there's a canonical GitHub issue about it. Haven't found one yet; I'll come back and edit if I find one.  My best guess about the cause for the error is that the [`Parameters<F>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) inside of the function implementation is an "unresolved generic conditional type"; the compiler doesn't know what `F` is, and doesn't want to commit to evaluating `Parameters<F>` until it does know it.  Which it just won't inside the function, unless you try to assign `params` to another variable or use a type assertion.

---

The compiler apparently does not know for sure that `F`, whatever it is, will have as many arguments as `foo` does, so it gives an error.  It turns out that the `bar2()` implementation is unsafe.

One of the assignability rules in TypeScript is that a function of fewer parameters is assignable to a function of more parameters.  See [the FAQ entry on the subject](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) for why this is desirable (short answer: it's usually safe to assume a function will just ignore extra arguments, and this is how most people write callbacks that don't need all the passed-in parameters):

```
const baz = () => "hello";
const assignableToFoo: typeof foo = baz; // no error
```

The fact that this assignment is allowed means that `F extends typeof foo` can be specified with something you're not intending.  Imagine `foo()` did something that actually cares about the types of its arguments:

```
function foo(a: number, b: boolean, c: string): string {
  return `success ${a.toFixed(2)} ${b} ${c.toUpperCase()}`;
}
```

Then you could call `bar2()` like this, according to its definition:

```
console.log(bar2<typeof baz>()); // compiles fine, but:
// RUNTIME ERROR  TypeError: a.toFixed() no good if a is undefined!
```

Since `F` is `typeof baz`, then `Parameters<F>` is `[]`, and `bar2()` can be called with no arguments, and `params` might be empty.  The error inside `bar2` is warning you, correctly, that `foo(...params)` is potentially dangerous.

---

Now because you said that this is a simplified example, I'm not 100% sure how best to write a version of `bar2`'s signature that captures the desired use cases.  Usually generic type parameters should correspond to some actual value; but there is no value of type `F` involved when calling `bar2()`, just a value whose type is the same as its argument list.  With the example code as written, I'd say that you should just use your non-generic `bar()`.

---

Finally, if you decide that you don't care about the possibility that `F` will be narrower than `foo` in such a way as to shorten its argument list, then you can just pretend that `params` is of type `Parameters<typeof foo>` (in fact I think the compiler will let you unsafely "widen" it to a variable of that type, even though it probably shouldn't):

```
function bar2<F extends typeof foo>(...params: Parameters<F>) {
  const _params: Parameters<typeof foo> = params;
  return foo(..._params); // no error now
}
```

But be careful!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIsIC2ARgKYBOANIoToagDbEZiUQ4DOUpMYA5gJTtO3HogDeAKESJSxKCFJIABmxAQIxNm0QASURgB0UOADEYAD2IATNACY+AXx2jCj3RENwAqgAdvZAMIYbMRoDooA3OL24uIQCGxwDPp0cDxoAEQocOl8kXFgCUkpaVloAIyUnCDElOmEGABeOXwxoJCwCFQYpGj6fd7dGPhsOAAKg-iyZGwAPFAAnn5wwMioAHx8YpLSsvJIpX36A6RDbC3RsfGJxMmpGfWkOXlXRXcP5ZWk1bX1TXwt4ja0HgSAeNhmxkQxDMUGIYEsWgWSxWWTWvX6ExGiHGJ0msNIs2MGy2UnyHEQAH1jqcxhMpgS5otiMtVnA1ogALyIanDSJSGRyBSs9H6KmY3JRGKXApQLoNTmIUKc9npAAWxDoKXSzxliCCbBgPDAGEIDAAKiZUDgkcyUagFb9wogAPTO3BwKGkUhwUgxMnXW5pMGM5FytH-J2uxBxfDeGAMLTAbg1KggKBYcRRgBKngAcmaAJIAWQAoogS1mswB5LOIQC8G4BSncQZqZJa9PpwGEQMC04EsxCTYCsAEIpf7Xmk6t0bDlpYUbsU0GCPogqimp38AXPZWZrUyWVkFUqOSr1fNtUA)

Comment: Excellent deep dive, thank you very much! I've marked this as the correct answer as it satisfied my curiosity.Ultimately, I wasn't able to get around this is a satisfactory way without the unsafe option you described, so I fixed my real issue with a bit of a deeper refactor.